# use different terminal setting after ssh into another machine

Tags: macos, terminal

I would like to use different terminal setting after doing a ssh into another machine.  This would mean I could have my terminals to different machine using different colours.  Is this possible?  Thanks.

Comment: Look at customising the prompt in your shell

Answer (score 1):

## Yes! It absolutely is possible.

The colors and other aspects of your **prompt** are controlled by configuration files.

If you're using the default **bash,** shell then one place where you can configure your prompt is in a file in your home directory called `.bash_profile`.

Since the `.bash_profile` file has a "`.`" at the beginning of its name, it may not be visible in Mac Finder windows, but you can see it listed in your terminal among others in your home directory by entering `ls -al`.

You'll have a `.bash_profile` file on your own Mac, and you'll also have another one on each remote computer you log into. (Or if the file doesn't exist you're free to create it.)

Put a different prompt config string in each of those files to get different colors on each machine.

## What is a prompt config string, and how do you write a custom one?

**[This guide](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/)** has full information on all the options you can enter to configure your bash shell prompt, including its colors.

Answer (score 0):

Yup. This is possible.

For my laptops I put the following line in `.profile`:

```
export PS1="\[\033]0;\w\007\]\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ "
```

On my servers i put the line below in `.profile`:

```
export PS1="\[\033]0;\w\007\]\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ "
```

`32m` and `35m` define the colour.